# Image transform polar to cartesian

Tags: c#, image, perspective

I am making a project for my college that involves image manipulation or conversion from polar to cartesian in Visual Studio C#. I tried finding solution on web for my problem but haven't been able to find anything relevant. If someone can help or provide a terminology so that I can search web and find it myself I would be thankful.

So basicly in the next image is depicited the transformation I need to perform. The image on the left is input, and the image on the right is the output.

http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2014/11/26/Untitled0anK9.png

Anybody has any idea?

This is the pic that I have to transform for it to look like I am looking at it from the front.

deviantpics.com/images/2014/11/26/Slika2.jpg

This is what I did until today.

deviantpics.com/images/2014/11/26/Slika222222.png

The final problem is that I have to analyze the object and symbols on him and compare it to the picture and symbol of the last object (symbol comparison, in this case stars).

Comment: Without more context, it is very hard to tell what you mean here. Converting between polar and cartesian coordinate systems is pretty easy, and google will tell you lots of stuff, so presumably you mean something else? Are you trying to do radial distortion correction, or something?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to say what I want, that is why I provided a image in my opening post to illustrate what I mean. If I know terminology I could maybe find the answer on the net, but that is why I am asking here...

Comment: Your image does not help. Are you correcting photographs with lens distortion? Are the source images purely synthetic? Are you trying to create an anamorphic image, or undo an anamorphic transformation? Can you share an actual input image?

Comment: Yes. This is the pic that I have to transform for it to look like I am looking at it from the front.

http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2014/11/26/Slika2.jpg

Comment: Ah-hah. That's better. It sounds like what you're trying to do is to do perspective correction/reprojection of the scene. I would classify that as 'quite complex', and in need of some additional information about the angle of the camera relative to the scene, and its focal length, etc. Not much to do with polar/cartesian conversion. Been a few years since I did any of this though, might be able to dig up some old work tomorrow and see if it might help.

Comment: I am sure it will help, thanks :). The thing is, the object is not always at the same place so I can't optimize it for the one angle of the camera. I would like to see your projects for that. Thisis what I did until today.

http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2014/11/26/Slika222222.png

Comment: It sounds like there are too many variables. You can't see enough of the subject to work out camera angle very well, and if the camera will be at an arbitrary position and all you have to reconstruct the scene from is a tiny blurry image you're going to get terrible results. What is the *actual problem* you're trying to solve?

Comment: I need to see based on the marks (stars, which can be any symbol) if the object is the one that was analyzied before him... so bassicly image comparison, just compare two symbols (stars, circles, squares...). The problem is that camera is positioned like that and oobjects come very fast so the image i not at the same angle, but similar ones. I need to make comparison if it is the same symbols on current object as to the last one.

Comment: Can you please take the contents of these comments and add them to your original question, and correct the title, tags, etc?